# Python 2.7 cx_freeze: What are the risks of removing the encodings that I dont need?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

when I perform a cx_freeze on my application I get a list of encodings as follows:

```
m encodings.aliases
m encodings.ascii
m encodings.base64_codec
m encodings.big5
m encodings.big5hkscs
m encodings.bz2_codec
m encodings.charmap
m encodings.cp037
m encodings.cp1006
m encodings.cp1026
m encodings.cp1140
m encodings.cp1250
m encodings.cp1251
m encodings.cp1252
m encodings.cp1253
m encodings.cp1254
m encodings.cp1255
m encodings.cp1256
m encodings.cp1257
m encodings.cp1258
m encodings.cp424
m encodings.cp437
m encodings.cp500
m encodings.cp720
m encodings.cp737
m encodings.cp775
m encodings.cp850
m encodings.cp852
m encodings.cp855
m encodings.cp856
m encodings.cp857
m encodings.cp858
m encodings.cp860
m encodings.cp861
m encodings.cp862
m encodings.cp863
m encodings.cp864
m encodings.cp865
m encodings.cp866
m encodings.cp869
m encodings.cp874
m encodings.cp875
m encodings.cp932
m encodings.cp949
m encodings.cp950
m encodings.euc_jis_2004
m encodings.euc_jisx0213
m encodings.euc_jp
m encodings.euc_kr
m encodings.gb18030
m encodings.gb2312
m encodings.gbk
m encodings.hex_codec
m encodings.hp_roman8
m encodings.hz
m encodings.idna
m encodings.iso2022_jp
m encodings.iso2022_jp_1
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2004
m encodings.iso2022_jp_3
m encodings.iso2022_jp_ext
m encodings.iso2022_kr
m encodings.iso8859_1
m encodings.iso8859_10
m encodings.iso8859_11
m encodings.iso8859_13
m encodings.iso8859_14
m encodings.iso8859_15
m encodings.iso8859_16
m encodings.iso8859_2
m encodings.iso8859_3
m encodings.iso8859_4
m encodings.iso8859_5
m encodings.iso8859_6
m encodings.iso8859_7
m encodings.iso8859_8
m encodings.iso8859_9
m encodings.johab
m encodings.koi8_r
m encodings.koi8_u
m encodings.latin_1
m encodings.mac_arabic
m encodings.mac_centeuro
m encodings.mac_croatian
m encodings.mac_cyrillic
m encodings.mac_farsi
m encodings.mac_greek
m encodings.mac_iceland
m encodings.mac_latin2
m encodings.mac_roman
m encodings.mac_romanian
m encodings.mac_turkish
m encodings.mbcs
m encodings.palmos
m encodings.ptcp154
m encodings.punycode
m encodings.quopri_codec
m encodings.raw_unicode_escape
m encodings.rot_13
m encodings.shift_jis
m encodings.shift_jis_2004
m encodings.shift_jisx0213
m encodings.string_escape
m encodings.tis_620
m encodings.undefined
m encodings.unicode_escape
m encodings.unicode_internal
m encodings.utf_16
m encodings.utf_16_be
m encodings.utf_16_le
m encodings.utf_32
m encodings.utf_32_be
m encodings.utf_32_le
m encodings.utf_7
m encodings.utf_8
m encodings.utf_8_sig
m encodings.uu_codec
m encodings.zlib_codec
```

However at the top of every file (even the **init**.py) I have the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Would this be enough information to remove the rest of the encodings and is there any risk in manually excluding them through the excludes list?

```
buildOptions = dict(packages = [],
                    excludes = ["encoding.cp1006", "encoding.cp037"],
                    includes = [], path=[], include_files=[])
```

Comment: Most of them can probably be safely excluded, but they're not just used for your source files - if any code, including modules you're importing, does something like `s.decode('punycode')`, it will need the corresponding codec. At a minimum you should leave ascii, utf_8, latin_1, cp1252 and mbcs  there.

Comment: Okay, thanks Thomas, I am including wx which is probably doing that s.decode.

Comment: No problem. I started out commenting and ended up writing a small answer, so I'm going to repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, most of the codecs can probably be safely excluded, but it's hard to be sure which ones are needed. They're not just used for your source files - if any code, including modules you're importing, does something like `b.decode('punycode')` or `u.encode('cp860'), it will need the corresponding codec.

At a minimum you should leave ascii, utf_8, latin_1, cp1252 and mbcs there, those are common ones to use. Oh, and `charmap` might be a base class, so it's probably safest to leave that in.

Notes on the other ones:

- The codecs starting with `cp` are Windows/DOS codepages, and may be encountered running on Windows in different locales.
- The `iso8859` family are similar on older Unix systems (modern Linux and Mac systems tend to use UTF-8).
- The `mac` family are similar for old Macs (pre OS X? I'm not sure)
- UTF-16 might be used on Windows for handling unicode.
- Code manipulating Python source code might use `string_escape` and `raw_unicode_escape`.
- base64, hex and uu are different ways of transforming binary data into text (to display it, or to put it in text-only formats like JSON)
- bz2 and zlib are compression algorithms.
- idna and punycode are used for handling internationalised domain names
- UTF-32 and UTF-7 are alternative ways of storing unicode, not explicitly used very often (Python can actually store strings as UTF-32 in memory, but I don't think it uses `codecs.utf_32` for that).
- Most of the others are encodings for far-eastern (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) text. It should be possible to handle that with Unicode now, but from what I've heard, some of those encodings are still in common use.

That should give you a rough idea what your application might need, but don't forget that some library you're using might use a codec in an unexpected way. It's not normal for code to handle some of the standard codecs being missing.